# How to use tab's URL outside chrome.tabs.query

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

this works fine

```
var tabUrl;

chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    tabUrl = tabs[0].url;
    console.log(tabUrl);
});
```

but this show undefined

```
var tabUrl;

chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    tabUrl = tabs[0].url;
});

console.log(tabUrl);
```

However I want to check URL to change my popup.html according to the page that user is browsing but I don't want to do this all inside chrome.tabs.query function

Comment: Review async concepts [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Thank you so much @IvánNokonoko

Answer (score 0):

According to W3's specification of how Javascript variables scope work. In order to access variables inside a function, you must not add the var sign before, and use window.Variable to access it.

This should work:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {

tabUrl = tabs[0].url;
});


console.log(window.tabUrl);
```

Comment: `chrome.tabs.query` works asynchronously. The variable `window.tabUrl` will still be undefined because it is accessed before the callback function is executed.